# drupal button appears after clicking on a first button

Tags: drupal

I want to create a drupal form, with a list select and a submit button, I just want to add a condition when I select a specific think, another button appears.

Example : a list select with items : show button 2 (when I select this item and I submit by clicking on the first button, another button appears)

This is my select list:

```
$form['select_list'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('select :'),                     
    '#options' => $form['select_list']['#value'],
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['storage']['select_list']) ? $form_state['storage']['select_list'] : '',


);
```

and this is my first button (always shown)

```
$form['button1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('button1')                 
    );
```

this is the button I want to be displayed when I select some item on the list:

```
$form['button2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('button2')                 
    );
```

which properties I should add to button1 or button2 or both?

Answer (score 1):

Got it,

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states

```
$form['button2'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('button 2'),
  '#states' => array(
    'invisible' => array(
      ':input[name="list_select"]' => array('value' => 'show button 1'), //everything except button 2
    )
  ),
);
```